# UseExistingEmptyCollectionDatabase must be set to true when creating a collection using a Managed Service Identity to authenticate with SQL

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I have Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.1 installed in an Azure VM, then configured it to connect with backend SQL Azure database, I followed the Azure DevOps documents
[Use Azure SQL Database with Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/install-azure-sql?view=azure-devops-2020) however, it failed with below messages.
I did similar against Azure DevOps Server 2020 version before, it succeeds. so not sure it is some problem with new version

```
[Info   @16:41:55.887] +-+-+-+-+-| Running General: Verifying that all the inputs are valid and there are no violations |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @16:41:55.902] 
[Info   @16:41:55.903] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that all the inputs are valid and there are no violations |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @16:41:55.903] Starting Node: VINPUTS
[Info   @16:41:55.903] NodePath : VINPUTS
[Info   @16:41:55.905] Node returned: Error
[Error  @16:41:55.905] UseExistingEmptyCollectionDatabase must be set to true when creating a collection using a Managed Service Identity to authenticate with SQL.
[Info   @16:41:55.905] Completed General: Error
[Info   @16:41:55.905] -----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

According the error info, we recommend you can check your ini file, and try to set the UseExistingEmptyCollectionDatabase=true. You can refer this doc: [Create the ini file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/unattended?view=azure-devops-2019#create-the-ini-file)

Comment: Thanks, I configured the Azure DevOps in Admin console, so it seems there is no ini file, it is mainly for unattended config. so are there any other place to update it? BTW, I am confused why we need update it. perhaps it is something with the installation file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the root cause, there is a problem with Azure DevOps 2020.0.1 ISO. with this version, 'New deployment-Azure' options is disabled when configuring Azure DevOps! so we can't select to use Azure SQL at all. in my case, I just select the 'New deployment -Basic', then encounter the above error!

I had another machine installed with Azure DevOps server 2020.1 RC1, and the 'New deployment-Azure' option can be selected, and it works!

Maybe the product team can take a look as well. [image]

Comment: I am glad that you have resolved your question. Before you get response form the product team, would you please convert your comment to the answer? This can be beneficial to other community members reading the answer, avoid spending a lot of time on a post that already has an answer.